# How do I make IPython reload a file passed to `ipython -i ...`

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, reload, read-eval-print-loop

I have a file /tmp/throwaway_code.py with something like

```
def hello():
    print("world")
```

and try it with IPython:

```
$ ipython3 -i /tmp/throwaway_code.py
In [1]: hello()
world
```

now I changed something in the file and want to reload. How do I do it without restarting IPython or modularizing the code?

My failed attempt:

```
In [2]: %load_ext autoreload

In [3]: %autoreload 2

# change source file    

In [4]: hello()
world
# Expected: world2.
```

Alternatively, how do I leave and re-enter IPython session with minimal effort (currently 6 keystrokes: Ctrl, D, y, Return, Up, Return)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autoreload` won't work here, the module isn't placed in `sys.modules` with the `-i` option:

```
from sys import modules

modules['throwaway_code'] # KeyError
```

so `reload` won't find the module you want it to reload.

A way around it is to explicitly `import` the module which places it in `sys.modules`, then `autoreload` will grab the changes each time. So you should exit IPython and start it with appropriate `PYTHONPATH` so that your code can be imported as a module. Your session should look like this:

```
In [4]: ^D
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp ipython3

In [1]: from throwaway_code import *

In [2]: %load_ext autoreload

In [3]: %autoreload 2

In [4]: hello()
world

In [5]: hello()
world2
```

Answer (score 0):

In IPython3, with reload(mymodule), you can reload all modules in the same package. Just paste this code at reload.py in IPython3 startup folder(On Ubuntu is "~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/")

```
import importlib

from types import ModuleType
import compileall
from filecmp import dircmp
from os.path import dirname
from glob import glob
from os.path import join


blacklist=[]
def reload(module,blacklist_appendix=[]):
    """Recursively reload modules."""
    file_paths=glob(join(dirname(module.__file__),"*.py"))
    print(file_paths)
    _reload(module,blacklist+blacklist_appendix,file_paths)



def _reload(module, blacklist=[],file_paths=[],reloadeds=[]):


    if module.__name__ in blacklist:
        print("not reloaded: "+module.__name__)
        return False

    if (module.__dict__.get("__file__")==None
        or not (module.__file__ in file_paths)
        or module.__file__ in reloadeds):
        return False

    reloadeds.append(module.__file__ )
    for attribute_name in dir(module):
        attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)

        if type(attribute) is ModuleType:
            _reload(attribute,file_paths=file_paths,reloadeds=reloadeds)


    compileall.compile_file(module.__file__,force=True)
    print("reload start: "+module.__name__)
    importlib.reload(module)
    print("reloaded: "+module.__name__)
```